# Creating Multiple Documents in MongoDB With Single JSON Web Token

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, jwt

**EDIT: *I realize that adding these components as a subdocument to my user is also possible. However, I am not sure if this is best practice? What would you all recommend?***

I'm currently building an application that uses Express, Node, and MongoDB to allow users to sign in. I would like to be able to adapt the code so that, when someone creates an account, it creates two documents: the user document, and a "tracker" document associated with that user.

My current code uses JSON Web Tokens. When a user document is saved, I'd like to be able to create a "tracker" document with the same "tokens" array so that I can easily restrict access to an Express route handling data in that tracker document to the appropriate user. Here's the route, and the code that runs when I create an instance of a user, which provides the JSON token:

```
app.post("/users", (req,res) => {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
    var user = new User(body);

    /// Maybe do tracker.save() here?

    user.save().then(() => {
        return user.generateAuthToken();
    }).then((token) => {
        res.header("x-auth", token).send(user);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    });
});
```

And the function that creates the web token:

```
UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function () {
    var user = this;
    var access = 'auth';
    var token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id.toHexString(), access}, process.env.JWT_SECRET).toString();

    user.tokens = user.tokens.concat([{access, token}]);

    // And then add it to the tracker as well?

    return user.save().then(() => {
        return token;
    });
};
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to add the token variable to the "tracker" document as well. The problem is, my "tracker" document hasn't been created yet.

**Could I tell the application to create the tracker document before creating the user, and then append the generated token to it? How would I do this? My comments in the code outline what I was thinking.**

Or is there a better strategy? I'm not opposed to keeping the user and their tracking data in the same document (perhaps a subdocuments for the tracking data, a subdocument for the settings, etc.) but am not sure how this would work. Please let me know your thoughts! The full code for my server is on my Github here: https://github.com/KingOfCramers/boilerplate_jwt_node_api/tree/master/server